# PHP REST Api error

Tags: php, rest

I wrote a custom framework to handle our `REST API` calls using the Flight framework as an example for our system using `AngularJS`. I have a problem with one particular file and I cannot move foward. I have an `index.php`file at `/api/v1/` folder to create a new object of the framework and handle routes with it:

```
<?php
require '.././libs/Fury/autoload.php';
require_once '.././system/database.php';
require_once('.././helpers/passwordHash.php');

use Fury\Engine;
$db  = is_null(DB_HOST) ? null : new Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
$app = new Engine();

require_once('auth.php');
require_once('projects.php');

function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    global $app;
    $app->json($response, $status_code);
}

$app->start();
```

I have required auth.php and projects.php in the file for separate routes so I can keep better track of them. This is one route from auth.php which works just fine and returns session data:

```
<?php
$app->route('GET /session', function() use ($db) {
    $session = Session::getSession();
    echoResponse(200, $session);
});
```

But for some reason projects.php gives me an error with this route

```
<?php
$app->route('GET /projects', function() use($db) {
    $rows = $db->all("SELECT * FROM projects");
    echoResponse(200, $rows);
});
```

Error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: app in \project\api\v1\projects.php on line 3

Fatal error: Call to a member function route() on a non-object in \project\api\v1\projects.php on line 3
```

Basically $app is not passed there or something else is wrong and I just cannot figure out what. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently this particular error was caused because the file was `projects.php` and it was `GET /projects`. I don't know why, but changing `projects.php` to `project.php` fixed the issue.